# How to access Woo Commerce products from within custom theme?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

On a custom Wordpress theme, I'm looking to access the product info of products created using the Woo Commerce plugin. Can global product objects be pulled from anywhere within the php files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can - see here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html

You'd use something like `$myproduct = new WC_Product( $product_id );`

Hope that helps